# Beamer presentation - Left to right direction and links in ToC doesn't work properly for Persian text

Tags: beamer, pandoc, markdown

I'm using [beamer](/questions/tagged/beamer) presentation with [markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown) and [pandoc](/questions/tagged/pandoc). I have a markdown file like this:

```
---
lang: fa
dir: rtl
title: "عنوان ارائه"
author: "نام دانشجو"
date: "تاریخ"
institute: "نام دانشگاه"
theme: "metropolis"
---

# فهرست

1. [شماره ۱](#شماره-۱)
2. [شماره ۲](#شماره-۲)


# شماره ۱
متنی در مورد شماره ۱

# شماره ۲
متنی در مورد شماره ۲
```

And I'm trying to convert it to PDF, using this command:

```
pandoc pres.md -t beamer -o pres.pdf --pdf-engine=xelatex -V mainfont="Sahel"
```

But there are two problems.

1. **Not everything goes RTL.**

[image]

As you can see, the author, date, and institute elements are in the correct direction, but the title isn't. Also, list elements in Table of Contents aren't in the right direction:

[image]

But I thought specifying `dir: rtl` would solve that. It does make a change when I add `dir: rtl`, but it's not working as expected.

2. **Links in Table of Contents don't work**

In the English version of the same markdown file, everything works. But when I change it to Persian, links don't work. And when I open the PDF file with `mupdf`, the moment I change the page to ToC, `mupdf` gives out this warning:

```
warning: undefined link destination
warning: ... repeated 2 times...
```

[image]

How can I fix these issues?

Answer (score 1):

Edit your code as:

```
---
lang: "fa"
dir: "rtl"
title: "عنوان ارائه"
author: "نام دانشجو"
date: "تاریخ"
institute: "نام دانشگاه"
theme: "metropolis"
header-includes: "\\raggedleft"
---

# فهرست
\raggedleft
۱. [شماره ۱](#شماره-۱)

\raggedleft
۲. [شماره ۲](#شماره-۲)


# شماره ۱
متنی در مورد شماره ۱

# شماره ۲
متنی در مورد شماره ۲
```

Output:
[image]
 Links in Table of Contents do work. [Pdf](http://s7.picofile.com/d/8389202500/6de5fa36-d695-462c-bcc2-4ba5ee486214/pres.pdf)

Suggestion: beamer example and template on @Tex_Ahmadi [Telegram channel](https://t.me/Tex_Ahmadi) .